# dispatchTouchEvent returns false in activity android

Tags: android, events, touch

My goal is to simulate a touch on the screen. I want to keep it simple so I didn't assign the dispatchTouchEvent to any view and let activity to call this method.

I want my program to touch the screen in a fixed period and repeat, so I make a Timer and Timer task to hold the method.

I turned on the "Show touch trace" in developer options but I didn't see any touch traces. Also the result the method returns is false which I used a log to get. Could you offer some suggestions to my codes? where could possibly go wrong? Thank you!

I tried adding super or this before dispatchTouchEvent but it gives me an error. :(

Here is the code:

```
Button button;
MotionEvent motionEvent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            beginTimer();
        }
    });
    //touch event
    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    float x = 500.0f;
    float y = 500.0f;
    // List of meta states found here: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
    int metaState = 0;
    motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
            downTime,
            eventTime,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
            x,
            y,
            metaState
    );
}
public void beginTimer() {
    final Runnable setRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                Log.d("clickEvent", String.valueOf(dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent)));
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(setRunnable);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 1000, 1000);
}
```

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: first use Handlers indtead of Timers/TimerTasks, second you have to obtain the event each time you want to dispatch it

Comment: Thank you! I changed the timer to handler and it took me quite a while to figure out how to do touch event. It finally turns out that I need to use adb to directly input touches otherwise I need to get permissions which is impossible. :)